# CSS classList.add makes out of order list. CSS style gets ignored. CSS does not cascade

Tags: javascript, html, css

This on Chrome 76.

When a div is clicked on, the div style changes. This is implemented by adding a highlight style class to the end of the classList.   When highlighting is removed, the highlighting class is removed, so styling goes back to what it was before, whatever that was.

This works almost all of the time, but sometimes after the classList.add(highlighting_style)  is called, the highlighting style is ignored.

I've distilled the problem down to a simple example that changes the border color of a div.  From this I can see that what happens is when classList.add is used to add a style to the classList, that it sometimes inserts that new style early in the list, where it then gets overridden by styles later in the list. a style that is applied later, is inserted before older styles already in the classList.  Hence cascading doesn't actually work.

Here is the example index.html file.  Open the console, set a breakpoint, and step through the classAdd commands to watch the classList order to change in the console (screenshots attached).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="no_cascade.css">
</head>
<body class="primitive">
  <script> 
    let element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "zbox";  // just supposing how the external program might style its element
    document.body.appendChild(element); // just supposing that the external program is displaying this
    element.classList.add("cyan");
    element.classList.add("red");
    element.classList.add("green");
    element.classList.add("gold");
    element.classList.add("yellow");
    element.classList.add("azure");
    element.classList.add("black");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is no_cascade.css:

```
.html{
    background:tan
}

.zbox{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.green{
    border-color: green;
}

.cyan{
    border-color: cyan;
}

.red{
    border-color: red;
}

.gold{
    border-color: gold;
}

.yellow{
    border-color: yellow;
}

.azure{
    border-color: azure;
}

.black{
    border-color: black;
}
```

What happens when I step through this in the debugger,  first we get a cyan border as expected.  Then a red one as expected.  Then the green one is ignored and it is still red.  Then the gold one, then the yellow one, etc. as expected.  The styling engine just does not like that third color.  It doesn't seems to be color name specific, rather the third one is just going to be ignored.

Now when watching the element listing while stepping through the code, as per the attached screenshots, we can see what happens.  First there is the cyan styling.  Then the red styling comes later in the classList, so the earlier styling is overridden by the later styling, as expected, and the border turns red.  However, when the green styling is added,  classList.add places it *earlier* in the list than the red styling, so the red styling still comes last, and the border is still red! Then when gold is added, it goes later in the list and the border turns gold, then it turns yellow, then asure, then black as each is added to the end of the class list.

So how can I add style such that I can do cascading, i.e. make sure the style in the list is in the same order that it is added to the list?  Or, how can I  set the order? How can I know the order? (because without knowing the order I can't control the style)

```
after first step, border set to cyan [1]
after second step, border set to red [2]
after third step, border set to green, but remains red[3]
after 4th step border changes to gold as expected[4]
```

further steps behave as expected
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOIh.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gL5k.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0N4M.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkAmE.png

Comment: i understand what you feel

Answer (score 2):

The cascade doesn't care what order the classes appear on the element.

It only cares about specificity (equal in this case), `!importance` (not in use here), the source of the CSS (always the author in this case) and **order in the stylesheet** … which is fixed.

If you only want one of the rulesets to apply: Remove the other classes.

Comment: so to use css, I have to scan the css list, find all the applicable prior styles, ones which my code may not even have made, store them somewhere, manufacture new styles to replace them, ones without conflicting fields, remove them, add in the new replacements along with the highlighting style.  Then upon removing highlighting,  I should remove all the modified styles,  remove the highlighting style, then replace the modified ones?  This is your proposed solution for having a style that highlights a div when clicked?  What happened to 'cascading' part of style sheets if I'm doing it manually?

Comment: @user244488 — No. I said to remove the other classes, not remove the other rulesets. e.g.  `element.className = "red"` instead of adding to the existing classes.

Comment: that is a very simple example to illustrate the issue.  Real classes will have many style fields, and real highlighting may also.  I can't just delete prior styling classes without side effects,  also I can't just delete it and throw it away, it has to get put back when the element is 'deselected'.  So your answer, as far as I understand it, does amount to the summary in the prior comment.

Comment: @user244488 the bottom line is that if at some point you've added a class to an element, and then at some later point you no longer want that class to take effect, you have to *remove* it. That's the way browsers work.

Comment: @pointy  classes that appear later on the stylesheet have precedence in determining style. You don't have to remove the prior one to make that happen.  In fact, there is my solution.  I changed the order of the style sheet and now it works.

Comment: Right, and the order of classes in the `.classList` does not make any difference at all. If you add a color class from the end of the CSS file, then subsequently adding a color from closer to the top of the file will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The cascading part refers to the order of their definitions in your .css file, not the order they appear on the element. To get the functionality you want, you're better off remove the previous color when you add a new one.

Comment: hmm, that sounds like a proposal to not use css.  Instead to use javascript functions that directly manipulate style on elements.  This javascript function would gets the computed style, saves the values for the fields to be changed, then change them.  Later another function then puts back the old values.  The problem with this is that the people who know how to make pages pretty want to edit .css classes.  So say, one adds a configuration file that such javascript programs read - then we are reinventing css ...

Comment: No... just use javascript to add and remove the color classes, not the actual styles. If the classes are scoped to what they should be actually doing in your case (changing the color), then this is pretty simple and should not create side effects. It's quite common practice.

Comment: so the entirety of existing css must be redesigned to accommodate partitioning out separately  style that a later feature add changes.  So we would have class widget_styling  and class widget_styling_that_selection_changes  partitioning out that second part.   I can see that given that classList.add does not guaranteed that adding to a class list puts the added class to the end of the list (or in a specified place) does imply that css design must be done in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you to understand more about specificity.
There is also the options to use more out of `Element.classList` and prefixing your colors `color-yellow, color-green, color-red` etc..

```
//check and fetch:: Element.classList
Element.classList.replace('color-green', 'color-red')
```

- [MDN web docs: specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [css SPECIFISHITY](https://specifishity.com/)

```js
//options 1 :: direct manipulation by javascript

const elem = document.getElementById('mySupermagicBox');
let valueOfDip = 0;

function dip() {

  valueOfDip = (valueOfDip === 0) ? 1 : (valueOfDip === 1) ? 2 : 0;

  if (valueOfDip === 0) {
    elem.style.removeProperty("background-color");
  }

  if (valueOfDip === 1) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //specificity 1/0/0/0
  }

  if (valueOfDip === 2) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; //specificity 1/0/0/0
  }
}
```

```css
/**** option 2 :: CSS rule specificity *****/

#x>#mySupermagicBox {
  background-color: lime;
  /*** specificity 2/0/0  ***/
}

#x {
  background-color: tan;
  /*** specificity 1/0/0 ***/
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <div id="mySupermagicBox">-no content-</div>
</div>
<!-- Button is for demonstration purpose only  -->
<button onclick="dip()">xXx</button>
```

Comment: just as a comment,  that MDN link states "When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. "   Another commenter suggests that 'last in declaration' applies only to the scanning order of the file, not to classes added via  classList.add.   When viewing the classList order on the console, one can see that the last (highest up) style applies.  So it seems that where things go wrong is that classList.add doesn't always put things at the end of the classList.

Comment: very correct, that way you can manipulate the `DOMTokenList` by not using `Element.classList`but use a method of your own.

Comment: yes, those links and this post indeed did help me understand.  So I just moved the class I wanted to be last in the classList to the bottom of the file.  When classList.add() sees it, it adds it last.  I hope this is how it is supposed to work.